# Spring Boot not obeying command line arguments

Tags: java, spring

Put together a very basic Spring Boot RESTful backend with some CRUD endpoints. Trying to start it up on my Centos7 server. However I already have an application listening on its default port, 8080, so I have to configure that.

I have tried:

`java -jar target/rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --server.port=8090`

`java -jar target/rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --Dserver.port=8090`

`java -jar target/rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --port=8090`

`java -jar target/rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar --Dport=8090`

My application.properties contains the line:

`server.port=${port:8090}`

Spring Boot still starts up the embedded Tomcat container on port 8080. It's not getting the message. What am I missing?

Edit: setting `SERVER_PORT=8090` was effective - see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `-Dserver.port=8090` note single `-` 
or 
`server.port=xxxx` in application.properties file

**EDIT:-**

Check your log, below line will echo in console `2015-10-16 23:13:23.082  INFO 4228 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)`

VM arg overrides application.properties

Comment: Good catch, I tried `java -jar target/rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dserver.port=8090`
...but it's still attempting 8080

Comment: did you check the logs, what port it's printing in logs and spring boot version?

Comment: I just tried on my environment with VM arg  [`-Dserver.port=8090`], and it worked. am using 1.2.6 version

Comment: I'm getting the following.

`2015-10-16 15:05:19.636  INFO 29659 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)`

Spring Boot version is v1.2.5.RELEASE

Comment: You have port in your properties so either `--port` or `-Dport` should work. You are on unix so `server.port` won't work you should use `SERVER_PORT` as variable.

Comment: @M.Deinum setting `SERVER_PORT=8090` worked! Perhaps it was already set by another embedded Tomcat application? I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "application.yml" or "application.properties" in the same folder of jar, the jar will take preference of the external configuration file.
Doesnt make sense for me, but its true. The springboot has higher priority to external configuration file instead the internal one.

Answer (score -1):

We have four different ways to change default port.

1. Using application.properties or application.yml
2. Implementing EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer interface
3. Using SpringApplication class
4. Change port directly through command line

For more details, visit below
http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/spring-boot-change-embedded-tomcat-default-port/